# How to execute a function after scrolling (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to scroll the page and then execute a function. This code gives me an error

```
No function was found that matched the signature provided.

window.scrollTo(0, 100, {
   onAfter : function(){
      alert('test');
   }
});
```

If I remove the third (settings) argument then the page scrolls. I also tried:

```
$('html,body').animate({
 scrollTop: 100,
 complete: function(){alert();}
}, 0);
```

It scrolls the page, but never calls alert.

Maybe I'm missing some small thing, but I don't know what it is! There are tons of examples, but none seem to work for me. They often have extra parameters and settings, and I'm unclear whether some use special libraries, besides jQuery.

EDIT: 2 requirements: It must be instant scroll and there must be a callback function after it's done. Just writing the next function on the next line does not work. My iPhone still does it out of order, I guess because scrollTop is still slow.

Comment: Why not use the `.scrollTop()` method instead? Looks like you are not animating anything here.

Comment: I need a callback function when it's done. Just writing the next function after scrollTop() doesn't work. My iPhone is slow to scroll (even with scrolltop) and completes the next function out of order, before scrolling has completed.

Comment: try using `.promise().done(function(){/* function after scroll */})` , here example on jsfiddle [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3skw3ccu/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76k339u1/1/)

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: 10000
    }, 0,

    function () {
        alert("hi");
    }
);
```

Comment: Not sure I get this. This will wait half a second and then execute a function, regardless of when the scrolling is done, no?

Comment: Yeah that was the gist. I've edited my answer to include another solution that may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, the first one works, thanks! (Remove the other and I'll mark it as right)

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `.animate()` method works. From official jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

`.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

You need to pass success callback as a separate argument, not a property of the first one. Plus, why 0 duration?

Try this:

```
$('html,body').animate(
    {scrollTop: 100},
    function () {
        alert();
    }
);
```

If you meant to do it without animation, there's `.scrollTop()` method (http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/):

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(100);
```

Comment: The animate one is slow (I really do want it to be instantaneous). Your scrollTop example does not call a function when done.

Comment: Why do you want to call a function when action is done, when this action takes 0 seconds? It doesn't make sense. You should just do it as next instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions with `animate` did not work for me - the function was executed before scrolling. So I just took advantage of synchronousness and I wrote two working versions of code:

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);        
alert('test');
```

or the second version with checking `if`:

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);         
if ($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
    alert('test');
}
```